# jquery toggle won't close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this code for an accordion style toggle. Works great, only problem is, if you click on an open accordion, it slides up then back down. It doesn't slide closed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

```
//toggles 2
$('body').on('click','.toggle h3 a', function(){

    if($(this).parents('.toggles').hasClass('accordion')) return false;

    $(this).parents('.toggles').find('.toggle > div').slideUp(300);
    $(this).parents('.toggles').find('.toggle h3 a i').attr('class','icon-plus-sign');
    $(this).parents('.toggles').find('.toggle').removeClass('open');

    $(this).parents('.toggle').find('> div').slideDown(300);
    $(this).parents('.toggle').addClass('open');

    //switch icon
    if( $(this).parents('.toggle').hasClass('open') ){
        $(this).find('i').attr('class','icon-minus-sign');
    } else {
        $(this).find('i').attr('class','icon-plus-sign');
    }

    return false;
});



<div class="toggles">

<div class="toggle accent-color"><h3><a href="#"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>First Accord</a></h3>
    <div>
    Content
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="toggle accent-color"><h3><a href="#"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>Second Accord</a></h3>
    <div>
    Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's something wrong with those '> div' selectors. Can we see the relevant html?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple why it does that. Your function always execute slideUp and slideDown. In that order. So when your div is collapsed, it will execute slideUp(which doesn't really make anything because it's already collapsed) and then it will slideDown. Now, when the div is expanded: The div will slideUp (this time it does go Up because it's not collapsed) and then it will go Down.

A better way to do it would be with SlideToggle.

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

**EDIT:** Also, you can check if the div is collapsed or not with...

```
if($(element).is(':visible')){
   //expanded
} else {
   //collapsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't really understand what was happening with your code so I rewrote the js part from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/d503n47r/2/

```
$('body').on('click','.toggle h3 a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parents('.toggles').hasClass('accordion')) return false;

    if ($(this).parents('.toggle').find('div').eq(0).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).parents('.toggle').find('div').eq(0).removeClass('open').slideUp();
    } else {
            $('.toggle.open').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parents('.toggle').find('div').eq(0).addClass('open').slideDown();
    }

});
```

Please take a look at jquery UI as it helps a lot with all this common things http://jqueryui.com/ (No need to reinvent the wheel)

Comment: Rewriting the part from scratch is great and all, but if you don't explain some of the things that you've added and maybe they haven't seen it's not going to benefit the original asker at all.

Comment: OK this is close... I just need it to close any open toggles if you click another toggle and open it... So only one can be open at once http://jsfiddle.net/d503n47r/8/

Answer (score 0):

MinusFour was correct that it was firing both at the same time.

A way to remedy this is to do an if / then statement that checks whether or not it's open, and then fire's the open / close dependent on that.

[Here's a link to a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb7h6rgz/3/)

I also added the class "toggle-panel" to the container that was sliding up / down, just so that following would be easier to read.

```
 if($(this).closest('.toggle').hasClass('open')){
        console.log('open');
        $(this).parents('.toggle').find('.toggle-panel').slideUp(300);
        $(this).closest('.toggle').removeClass('open');
        return
    }
    else {
        console.log('close');
        $(this).parents('.toggles').find('.toggle h3 a i').attr('class','icon-plus-sign');
        $(this).parents('.toggle').find('.toggle-panel').slideDown(300);
        $(this).parents('.toggle').addClass('open');
    }
```